# How to run the Play's dist file in the background?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, playframework

When I deployed my play application I built the package using:

```
dist
```

This created a file that I can run on my server like:

```
sudo ./bin/app-name -Dhttp.port=9090
```

This works fine for testing but how can I run this process in the background?

I will eventually have to use upstart or some sort of process monitoring tool to make sure this process is running after server reboots etc.

Using play 2.3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on ubuntu

```
sudo ./bin/app-name -Dhttp.port=9090 &
```

should do the trick.

Ceating the upstart script is also fairly easy https://askubuntu.com/questions/18802/how-to-correctly-add-a-custom-daemon-to-init-d
In your case it would be in /etc/init/app-name.conf and look like

```
# app-name
#   

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec $PATH_TO_APP/bin/app-name -Dhttp.port=9090
```

Of course you will want to change the RUNLEVEL and the PATH_TO_APP

Comment: I see, upstart is both a process monitor and start/stop script.  Something like this seems to be just a start/stop script: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/EmmanuelKasper/9698253/raw/1224649dc35d1b41212401d04ee85a48a937fdbd/play2_init_script  not process monitoring...

Comment: Your gist is a link to an init script which does provide start/stop but not respawn. careful with the upstart script: it is untested

Answer (score 0):

That of course depends on the system at which you're deploying the app, anyway in general you need to run it as a deamon.

Refer to your system's documentations, I'm pretty sure that you will find tutorial very soon.